# Running a simulator build via script

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator

I wanted to run my application on iPhone simulator via some script. Is it possible to launch the simulator without XCode or any manual intervention? Anybody tried this before?

Comment: Do you just want a script that opens the simulator, or one that opens an app within it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something like this would be your best bet.

http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/40157f763dfa1a34?pli=1

Other than that the only alternative I see would be to script a series of clicks on specific coordinates on the screen which would count on the simulator always being in the same place on the screen etc...

Have you done any work with AppleScript?